Why did Paul say "But to the rest I, not the Lord, say..." in 1 Cor 7:12?
According to 2 Timothy 3:16 "All Scripture is given by inspiration of God", why Paul said "But to the rest I, not the Lord, say" in 1 Cor 7:12?

Welcome to the group Ennon. I upvoted Jason's answer, but I would add that Paul didn't know he was writing scripture, so in humility he distinguished between his personal viewpoint and what Jesus had said and/or what he had received directly from God.

@DanFefferman interesting point – so Paul would likely be talking about OT – as there was no NT at the time, hence Paul's scriptures are not inspired

Short Answer: Because the Lord truly didn't say it.
Paul here distinguishes his own words from those that Jesus had explicitly taught for the duration of his earthly ministry. This distinction is what leads Paul to say, "But to the rest I, not the Lord, say."
This declaration by Paul does not suggest that his words are, one way or another, less authoritative or inspired than Jesus' teachings. Instead, it reflects the truth that Jesus had not addressed every precise circumstance or issue that could arise within the Christian community during his earthly ministry. In cases in which there's no direct teaching from Jesus, Paul, under the steering of the Holy Spirit, provides teaching based on the standards Jesus represented. 
To conclude: When Paul says, "But to the rest I, not the Lord, say" he is clarifying that what follows is his apostolic teaching based on divine inspiration rather than a quotation of Jesus' direct teachings. However, Paul's words are still taken as authoritative and as Scripture, as affirmed in 2 Timothy 3:16. 

+1. Good and precise answer.

@Dottard -- I think you forgot to actually upvote this answer although you gave it a +1.  One of the things I appreciate about Paul is that several times he makes it clear that this is his own opinion rather than something God revealed to him.

@DanFefferman - many thanks - done

Thank you so much for taking time to answer. I believe this could be precisely what I'm waiting for.

RE the final remark "as affirmed in 2 Timothy 3:16".  We know Paul considered Luke's gospel to be scripture because he quoted Luke 10:7 ("the laborer earns his wages") as scripture alongside Deuteronomy 25:4 ("you shall not muzzle an ox...") in 1 Timothy 5.  But just because we consider Paul's letters as scripture does not mean he himself shared that assessment.  It would have been quite arrogant for Paul to have considered his own letters to be "scripture" and having equal status to Torah, the Prophets, etc.

An extremely short answer - Because that letter to Christians in Corinth was not being generated by A.I.
There was a real, live, human author getting Greek words down on to parchment. He was not an automaton, a robot, or programmed by another to only write words dictated to him. Paul had a working mind, human feelings, and addressed his readers likewise. They knew, therefore, when he was instructing him as to God's revelations to humanity via Jesus Christ, and when Paul mentioned a point that was not from the lips of Christ. Yet it was still sound Christian counsel, entirely biblical in principle.

Thank you so much for taking time to help me with an answer.
